# How Do I Use Map Within a Function - Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple map script that takes an array and returns the nth column. Here is an example with n=2:

```
var array1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]];

var newArray = array1.map(function(column){
               return [column[2]]
              });
Logger.log(newArray);
```

I want to make this into a function where the User inputs an array `var data` and column number `var n` and gets back the nth column. Here is how I've written the function:

```
function selectCol(data,n){
  return data.map(function(column){
  return [column[n]]
  })
  }
```

When I attempt to use this function, for example:

```
var array1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]];
Logger.log(selectCol(array1,2));
```

I get the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

How do I incorporate `.map` into an actual function?

---

Per Robin's answer below, it appears I want to declare a dummy function at the beginning of the script and then select it as my main function:
[image]

Comment: Do you have `selectColumn` selected at the top? That will lead to the whole body being run once (to define everything) and then `selectColumn` being called with no arguments. You probably want some sort of `main` function that takes no arguments.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're saying. Can you please provide an example or more detail? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Apps Script you always select a function that is being run.

What then happens is that the entire script is being run and **then** the function is called with **no** arguments.

If you run your code you will notice that the output is probably logged and then the error appears out of nowhere.

That is because the main code is executed as part of the setup, the error is happening because `selectCol` is then called without arguments.

The solution is to have some `main` function that can be run without arguments.

Comment: I see! I added an image above to my original question. Is this what you are suggesting?

Comment: For example. In practice you'd probably want to put lines 18-20 into `myFunction` in case you add new functionality and you don't want selectCol to be run every time.

Comment: Thank you. Do you by chance have a reference for how this process works? I'm clearly lacking in this knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: I can only recommend the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview). I'm not sure if this particular point is made in any specific section though.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much. Super helpful. I found a great video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gofQzXnIg7w btw, for anyone who is also starting out and trying to understand what you described.